# Redshift COPY command delimiter not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to load some text files to Redshift. They are tab delimited, except for after the final row value. That's causing a delimiter not found error. I only see a way to set the field delimiter in the COPY statement, not a way to set a row delimiter. Any ideas that don't involve processing all my files to add a tab to the end of each row?

Thanks

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with missing `<tab>` at the end of lines. Are you sure that ALL lines have correct number of fields?

Run the query:

```
select le.starttime, d.query, d.line_number, d.colname, d.value,
le.raw_line, le.err_reason    
from stl_loaderror_detail d, stl_load_errors le
where d.query = le.query
order by le.starttime desc
limit 100
```

to get the full error report. It will show the filename with errors, incorrect line number, and error details.

This will help to find where the problem lies.

Comment: yes me too. thanks for this diagnostic query.. v nice.

Answer (score 51):

You can get the delimiter not found error if your row has less columns than expected. Some CSV generators may just output a single quote at the end if last columns are null.

To solve this you can use FILLRECORD on Redshift copy options.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue. I didn't find the "delimiter not found" very indicative that this could be the issue.

Comment: this was the problem I had. A tab-delimited file exported from Excel had no delimiter after the final row.

Answer (score 5):

From my understanding the error message `Delimiter not found` may be caused also by not specifying correctly the `COPY` command, in particular by not specifying the Data format parameters https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

In my case I was trying to load Parquet data with this expression:

```
COPY my_schema.my_table
FROM 's3://my_bucket/my/folder/'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::my_role:role/my_redshift_role'
REGION 'my-region-1';
```

and I received the `Delimiter not found` error message when looking into the system table `stl_load_errors`. But specifying I'm dealing with Parquet data in the expression in this way:

```
COPY my_schema.my_table
FROM 's3://my_bucket/my/folder/'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::my_role:role/my_redshift_role'
FORMAT AS PARQUET;
```

solved my problem and I was able to correctly load the data.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was answered, but I just dealt with the same error and I had a simple solution so i'll share it.

This error can also be solved by stating the specific columns of the table that are copied from the s3 files (if you know what are the columns in the data on s3).
In my case the data had less columns than the number of columns in the table.
Madahava's answer with the 'FILLRECORD' option DID solve the issue for me but then I noticed a column that was supposed to filled up with default values, remained null.

```
COPY <table> (col1, col2, col3) from 's3://somebucket/file' ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this pops up when you dont specify the file type, for example CSV

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-run-copy.html

```html
copy "dev"."my"."table" from 's3://bucket/myfile_upload.csv' credentials 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::2112277888:role/RedshiftAccessRole' IGNOREHEADER 1 csv;
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be directly related to the OP's question but I received the same `Delimiter not found` error which was caused by newline characters within one of the fields.

For any field that you think may have newline characters you can remove them with:

```
replace(my_field, chr(10), '')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you send fewer fields than expected on the destin table, it will also throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are multiple scenarios that would return this error. I just came across one that I don't see mentioned in the other answers while I was debugging someone else's code. The COPY had the EXPLICIT_IDS option listed, the table it was trying to import into had a column with a data type of identity(1,1), but the file it was trying to import into Redshift did not have an ID field.  It made sense for me to add the identity field to the file. But, I imagine removing the EXPLICIT_IDS option would also have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So recently I came across of this Delimiter not found error in Redshift SQL while loading the data with copy command. In my case, the problem was with column numbers.
I had created a table with 20 columns but I was loading the file with 21 columns.
I corrected it in my table by making 21 columns in the table and then re-loaded the data and boom it worked.

Hope it will be helpful to those who are facing the same kind of problem.
Ta-da

Answer (score 0):

I was copying data from Redshift => S3 => Redshift, and I ran into this issue when my data contained nulls and I was using `DELIMITER AS ','`.

I solved this by setting `NULL AS 'NULL'` (and using the default pipe delimiter).

These are the `UNLOAD` and `COPY` commands I used:

```sql
UNLOAD ('SELECT * FROM my_table')
TO 's3://my-bucket'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::123:role/MyRole'
NULL AS 'NULL'
ADDQUOTES
ESCAPE
ALLOWOVERWRITE;
```

```sql
COPY my_new_table
FROM 's3://my-bucket'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::123:role/MyRole'
NULL AS 'NULL'
REMOVEQUOTES
ESCAPE;
```